# To read JSF commandbutton action attribute value through javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

Hi is there any way through which i can read JSF command button action attribute value.My command button statement is

```
<h:commandButton id="cmdBtn" value="GO" action="#{managedBean.submit}"onclick="javascriptfunction()"/>
```

action attribute is getting value from managed bean and command button is within a form.

below is my select menu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="workspaceOptions"
            value="#{workSpaceBean.selectedItem}" class="selectMenu">
            <f:selectItem id="header" itemLabel="Select" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItem id="option1" itemLabel="Assignments" itemValue="assignment" />
            <f:selectItem id="option2" itemLabel="Preview" itemValue="preview" />
            <f:selectItem id="option3" itemLabel="Edit Coverage" itemValue="editCoverage" />
            <f:selectItem id="option4" itemLabel="attachment" itemValue="attachment" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:commandButton id="cmdBtn" value="GO" class="commandButton"
            action="#{workSpaceBean.submit}" onclick="javascriptfunction()" />`
```

For the options editCoverage,attachment i would be getting multiple outcomes based on some conditions in the managed bean.All i want to do is open the outcome views of these in new window and for remaining options need to remain in same page.

Comment: The problem seems little bit complex.I am selecting a selectmenu item and executing it through command button

Comment: The problem seems little bit complex.I am selecting a selectmenu item and executing it through command button.Most of the options needs control to stay in the same page except for two **which need a new window to be opened**.In the managed bean i return null for those which don't require navigation and  **the options which require new window in turn have multiple navigation cases each of which require new window to be opened.**I am returning view name for those options.i cannot use **target=_blank** since it opens main page also in new window.So i was trying to read action values using js.

Comment: so that i can read it through javascript and open the web page in new window for those particular options.

Comment: @BalusC please find my edited question.